Using simps in scipy for py-feat
I am trying to use py-feat, a Python app.
Trying to run it gives an error that simps cannot be imported from Scipy.
Starting with scipy 1.6, simps got changed into simpson (the latest version of scipy is 1.14). Trying to install Scipy 1.5 gives dependency errors.
How do I get py-feat to work?

Please provide enough detail specifically the dependency  errors so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

scipy.integrate.simps() was deprecated in 1.6.0, but it wasn't actually removed until 1.14.0, so 1.13.0 should still have it.
